# Why addClass does not work for DOM element in Angular?

Tags: angular, angular8

I have DOM component:

```
<app-ui-element-block (click)=do($event)></app-ui-element-block>
```

Method is:

```
public do($event){ 
   const elms = document.getElementsByTagName('app-ui-element-block');

        for (let i = 0; i < elms.length; i++) {
            elms[i].classList.remove('active');
        }

        $event.target.classList.add('active');
}
```

Why I can not set class for selected element DOM as component?

Comment: Why not use a more "angular way". You can use the [ngClass](https://angular.io/api/common/NgClass) directive instead.

Comment: I have specific case, look as question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you have a component named `UiElementBlock`, and you want this to have a class or not:

If these are placed using an `*ngFor`, you can use the looped element as indicator (or something else):

```
<app-ui-element-block
  *ngFor="let block of blocks"
  [class.active]="block === active"
  (click)="active = block">
</app-ui-element-block>
```

In your parent component you need to define this `active`:

```
export class ParentUiComponent {
  active?: UiElementBlock;

  blocks = [
    'ui1',
    'ui2',
    'ui3'
  ];
}
```

If you are not using the `*ngFor`, and you are manually placing these blocks, you also have the choice to manually assign a variable to it:

```
<app-ui-element-block
  [class.active]="block1 === active"
  (click)="active = block1"
  #block1>
</app-ui-element-block>

<div> Some random content </div>

<app-ui-element-block
  [class.active]="block2 === active"
  (click)="active = block2"
  #block2>
</app-ui-element-block>
```

Things get more wild if these components are spread across multiple parent components. You would need to do this logic inside the block itself, in combination with a service:

```
export interface ActivatableBlock {
  active: boolean;
}

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class UiElementBlockService {
  private active?: ActivatableBlock;

  activate(block: ActivatableBlock): void {
    if (this.active) {
      this.active = false;
    }

    block.active = true;
    this.active = block;
  }
}

@Component({
  selector: 'app-ui-element-block',
  template: ``
})
export class UiElementBlock implements ActivatableBlock {
  @HostBinding('class.active')
  active?: boolean;

  constructor(private ub: UiElementBlockService) {}

  @HostListener('click')
  onClick(): void {
    this.ub.activate(this);
  }
}
```

So, that's just a couple of ways of doing it, without using the DOM, and making things more reusable and easier to test.

Answer (score 2):

Why not use a more "angular way". You can use the [ngClass](https://angular.io/api/common/NgClass) directive instead.

```
<app-ui-element-block [ngClass]="{'active': isActive}" (click)="isActive=true"></app-ui-element-block>
```

Then you just need a field in your root component named `isActive`. If you have multiple items then you could either use an array or an indexer or something similar.

Comment: I have some <app-ui-element-block> on the page, in yours case I will activate all

Comment: @OPV - that does not matter, this pattern will work either way. The point is to move the logic into the root component but to apply the css class using `ngClass`. This is the "correct" way to do it, not to iterate over the DOM elements. If you want specific help with your logic you need to update your question with an [mcve].